# convert FormData files object to normal object

Tags: php, object, multipartform-data

i am sending files for uploading with FormData to PHP

```
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++)
                    {
                          var file = $scope.files[i];

                          console.log(file);


                        formData.append('photos[]', file);
                     };

                    console.log(formData);
```

and recieving this

```
[{"name":["file1.jpg","file2.jpg"],"type":["image\/jpeg","image\/jpeg"],"tmp_name":        ["C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpEF58.tmp","C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpEF78.tmp"],"error":[0,0],"size":[58286,250352]}]
```

as you can see its not right. how i want it to be:

```
[{"name": "file1.jpg", "type": "image\/jpeg",...,...},{"name": "file2.jpg", "type": "image\/jpeg",...,...}
```

how can i work with this for uploading? i am not even sure this is how i need it..

solved with:

```
jQuery.each($('input[type=file]')[0].files, function(i, file) 
        {
            formData.append(i, file);
        });
```